# Data Normalization: features same unit but different range

Tags: neural-network, normalization

In my neural network all features have the same unit (centimeter).
But the range of some features is very different e.g.

- range of feature1: 5cm to 6cm
- range of feature2: 12.5cm to 15cm
- range of feature3: 5.5cm to 12.5cm

Is normalization useful in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course its useful, you have to normalize your inputs and outputs, there is not much choice in that.

Comment: I am a bit confused because all features have the same units. Nevertheless I should normalize each feature individually?

Comment: @Ev4 Units don't really matter, and yes, normalization is done for each feature individually.